# How do I force iCloud to sync data of an App on fresh install / first launch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, cloudkit, gamekit

In a game I am working on I have implemented GKSavedGames and everything is working correctly except that if the game is uninstalled and reinstalled or installed on a new device the first initial launch `fetchSavedGamesWithCompletionHandler` returns 0 saved games.

Is there a way to force iCloud to sync the files to the device? I have tried waiting and recalling `fetchSavedGamesWithCompletionHandler` but nothing seems to work. If I immediately relaunch the app all the save files are then available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `GKSavedGames`, but if you are using CloudKit as your post's tag implies, then the following approach may help you.

1. In your app, check for the presence of a `UserDefault` with type `Date` named something like `lastUpdated`.
2. If the value of `lastUpdated` is `nil` (which it will be on a fresh installation of a device) then do a `CKQuery` to fetch all records.
3. After fetching the records, set `lastUpdated` to "now" using a new `Date()` object.
4. You can use the `lastUpdated` date in the future to check for stale data. For example, if `lastUpdated` is more than `n` days old compared to now, you can pull the records again.