# iOS 10 - Swift still Notification CloudKit: App is not launched, read Notification after didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, cloudkit

I have a problem with reading the notification when the app is not in background mode anymore. So it is completely off.
The notification setup works fine.
Even if the app is no longer in the background, the notification is read. In the log files you can see the arrival.
For testing purposes I have turned on the notification pointer. It counts up.

What works:
When the app is in the background:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {}
```

Correctly executed and I can access the data via the CKRecordID.

But if the app is no longer in the background, i.e. completely off, the fetchCompletionHandler is not executed anymore.
I have checked this via NSLog.

Now I need a way to read the notification again when the app is started. So I need the CKRecordIDs.

It is only about data that is transferred. I don't need a display on the screen.

It is also possible to change the settings so that only the data is received when the app is started again. I don't really need them in the background.

It is about a game to transfer data from one device to another.

Who has a code snippet for me?
Or a hint where I can search?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not a way to get missed notifications when the device is offline or the app is not running.

You are going to need to create a `CKQuery` to check CloudKit for what the device missed the last time it launched. Your `CKQuery` will have to compare against a timestamp saved locally to the device with `UserDefaults` to know what to fetch from CloudKit.

See my [answer here to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64021778/how-do-i-force-icloud-to-sync-data-of-an-app-on-fresh-install-first-launch/64033328#64033328) for a longer description of what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I had thought of something like that too.